# Receiving String... parameters and passing its values to other method that receives String ...parameters

Tags: java, string, variadic-functions

```
private String createURI (String URL , String... parameters) {
        if (parameters != null && parameters.length > 0) {
            return String.format(URL, "5435534", "John" , parameters[0].toString());
        }

        return String.format(URL, "5435534", "John");
    }
```

I created a method that should support in getting URL or URL+additional parameters and create from them a URL by the passed values.
of course the amount of %s in the URL should fit the amount of the parameters.

I use it like that:

`createURI ("%s/call/%s")`   ==> 5435534/call/John

`createURI ("%s/call/%s/%s" , "familyName")`  ==> 5435534/call/John/familyName

I didnt want to created something like this:
`String createURI (String URL , String parameter)` and just pass empty string when I don't want to use it and then check in the method whether the text is empty or not, and call the method the next way:

```
createURI ("%s/call/%s" , "") 
createURI ("%s/call/%s/%s" , "FamilyName")
```

my question is how can I improve it by sending exactly the arguments received to the String.format method without explicitly sending the [0] item - I don't want to check the values, the `String.format` doing it already but to String values. if I just passing the parameters as is (type String...) to `String.format(URL, "5435534", parameters)` it doesn't receive the actual string value but the full object.

Comment: Not quite sure what you try, but did you try to take a look at the string api https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html ?

Comment: I don't think you can use the `String.format` method in the manner you want. You'll probably need to use concatenation together with a loop instead.

Comment: Side note: If `parameters` is an array of `String`, using `toString()` on `parameters[0]` serves no purpose.  `parameters[0]` will be exactly the same as `parameters[0].toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String createURI (String URL , String... parameters) {
        ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
        strs.add("5435534");
        strs.add("John");
        strs.addAll(Arrays.asList(parameters);
        return String.format(URL, strs.toArray());
 }
```

You can **join** all parameters to **List** and convert it to **Array** for `String.format`. This way will no **if** for this. and need to call out: `varargs` default size is **0**.

Comment: This is a bit tricky.  It depends on the fact that `toArray()` with no parameters is defined to return `Object[]`.  See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--).  The code _looks_ like it should return `String[]`, which wouldn't work because `format` is defined to take an `Object[]`.  I wouldn't use code like this without an explanatory comment.

Answer (score 0):

`String.format()` (without a `Locale` parameter) takes two arguments: a format string, and an array of `Object`:

```
public static String format(String format,
                            Object... args)
```

Since the second argument uses `...` notation, you have two options for passing the second argument: either you can pass it an `Object[]`, or you can pass it zero or more arguments of any type that will then be bundled up into an `Object[]`.  Those are the only two choices.  You can't, say, pass two arguments, and then pass an array that the method will see as the third, fourth, etc. argument.  That array will be seen as a single argument.

However, you can create your own `Object[]` array, set the first two elements of the array, and copy the remainder in, something like:

```
Object[] formatParameters = new Object[parameters.length + 2];
formatParameters[0] = "5435534";
formatParameters[1] = "John";
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    formatParameters[i + 2] = parameters[i];
}
return String.format(URL, formatParameters);
```

Note that `formatParameters` has to be `Object[]` for this to work (I don't think it will work with `String[]`).  This is to get the compiler to realize that you're passing an array of parameters, instead of a single parameter whose type happens to be an array.

(Note: There should be methods in `Arrays` that could copy from `parameters` to `formatParameters` without a loop, but I don't feel like looking them up right now.)